# How to write a ruby application to be extensible via plugins

Tags: ruby, plugins, reflection, extending

For example - If I have an application and I want to create an object that will be imported though a plugin, how would I go about writing that?

I've put together an example - It works as I'm intending; however I'm not sure if this is the 'conventional' way to go about it.

Is there a more efficient, or proper way to do this in Ruby?

**start.rb**

```
require './cloud.rb'

dir = 'plugins'
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(dir)
Dir[File.join(dir, "*.rb")].each {|file| require File.basename(file) }

mycloud = CloudProvider.descendants.first.new


mycloud.say('testing')
```

**cloud.rb**

```
class CloudProvider

  def self.descendants
    ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |asdf| asdf < self }
  end
end
```

**plugins/aws.rb**

```
# This one inside plugins/
class AWS < CloudProvider
  def initialize

  end

  def say(val)
    puts val
  end
end
```

Comment: If your plugin is just something that implements an interface you specify, you shouldn't even have a base class.  In Ruby, you don't need to declare interfaces (as you do in Java, eg).  If an object responds to the methods of an interface, it implements them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) is a widely used Ruby project that provides [plugins](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/). I like their approach a lot:

1. Implement a base class that implements the basic functionality of your plugin (Jekyll has a few different types of classes you can inherit from).
2. Clearly specify what methods a subclass will have to override to make the plugin work.

Then you can have your user dump all their plugins in a `plugins` directory and load all the files as you're doing now. This approach is built on solid OO concepts and it's very clean.

One suggestion: Ruby provides a [inherited](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited) callback that you can use. This is much better than searching through all classes with `asdf < self`.

Comment: Heh. I just realized I kept in 'asdf' - I originally found that line as 'klass' and was testing to see if it was a special keyword as I've seen it around.

Comment: Thanks! Went ahead and read through this now that I had a few spare minutes - Very clean approach!